# Is allowDiskUse valid for find() method in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to test some theories on slow running queries - hence I *want* my query to run slow.  For this reason I have ommited indexes on my collection.  When I run `db.mycollection.find({myfield: /.abc./}).sort({myfield2: 1}, {allowDiskUse: true})` method I receive the following error...

```
Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Executor error during find command: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.",
        "code" : 96,
        "codeName" : "OperationFailed"
}
```

OK fine.  I want to continue to sort on disk, but it seems the aggregate framework command 'allowDiskUse:' does nothing on the find() method.  I receive the same error.

Is the 'allowDiskUse' valid when used with find() or is it only valid when used with the Aggregation Framework?

I can't seem to find any documentation that states it is framework specific but then again, it doesn't seem to work with find().  Maybe that's a loose answer.  I guess I am seeking a more concrete answer.

Comment: The `allowDiskUse` option is specific to the aggregation framework. You can remove `sort()` from your `find()` query to avoid hitting the in-memory sort limit. If you have indexes you want to ignore, you can also use `hint()` to [force a collection scan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#force-collection-scans) or non-optimal index (but the sort limit still applies).

Comment: Thx @Stennie.  Add your response as answer and I will award points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the 'allowDiskUse' valid when used with find() or is it only valid when used with the Aggregation Framework?

The `allowDiskUse` option is specific to the aggregation framework.

> Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM.

You can remove `sort()` from your `find()` query to avoid hitting the [in-memory sort limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Sort-Operations).

> I *want* my query to run slow.

While this isn't a typical goal, a few options to make this query slower are:

- Use `hint()` to [force a collection scan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#force-collection-scans) or non-optimal index choice (but the sort limit still applies)
- Make your [regex query case-insensitive](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use): `{myfield: /abc/i}`
- Limit the resources available to `mongod` using [`cgroups`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) or a virtual machine. Limited RAM (where your working set is significantly bigger than RAM) and slow disks can contribute to slow queries.

Comment: See my answer for Mongo 4.4

Answer (score 7):

In MongoDB version 4.4 this feature has been added: [cursor.allowDiskUse()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.allowDiskUse/index.html)

`allowDiskUse()` has the following form:

```
db.collection.find(<match>).sort(<sort>).allowDiskUse()
```